# Stripe Subscription URL With Custom Pricing

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to create a custom stripe subscription with dynamic pricing that can change depending on the user. But I'm struggling find any decent information about from the docs.

I mean I can generate stripe url with premade subscription product like the following,

```
  const paymentLink = await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
    line_items: [{price: "XXXX", quantity: 1}],
    metadata: {
        author_id: message.author.id,
    },
    
  });
```

But to create subscription link with custom pricing,

Do I have to create whole new subscription product through api and then generate a link?

Or is there a better way to generate links with dynamic pricing?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use dynamic pricing, I'd recommend using Checkout Session that creates an one-time payment link: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout

Instead of using `line_items.price`, you can use [`line_items.price_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data) which allows you to create amount at the time when you create a subscription. For example,

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  mode: 'subscription',
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        unit_amount: 1000,
        currency: 'USD',
        recurring: {
          interval: 'month',
        },
        product_data: {
          name: 'Music Streaming',
        },
      },
      quantity: 1,
    }
  ],
  // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
  // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
  // is redirected to the success page.
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/canceled.html',
});
```

Comment: After posting the question, I was trying to do it by creating a new price object using the product id and then generating the url using the price id. Is it a good idea to do it this way? Or should I only do it using session create method like u mentioned?

Comment: Both ways work, so it's totally up to you how you would like to manage the price. Please note the payment link is for multiple use whereas checkout session is for one-time use.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a lot of trouble